# Что если у пользователя отключен JS в AngularJS приложении?

Tags: angularjs, браузер

Добрый День, подскажите пожалуйста, как себя вести если все же найдется такой пользователь с отключенным JS, я предполагаю два вариантра развития событий:

1. Просто вывести сообщение об необходимости включить JS, инструкцию как это сделать, скачать и установить новый браузер(если пользователь использует IE6)
2. Нужно обеспечить минимальную фунциональность

Дело в том что почти весь контент на станицах я вывожу с помощью `ng-repeat` директивы. Как быть в такой ситуации ? Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: ангуляр - это js-framework, если js отключен - ангуляр не будет работать **совсем**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли в наше время рядовой пользователь серфит интернет с отключенном JavaScript, т.к. сейчас без него трудно представить популярные сайты. Но даже если так, то скорее всего пользователь знает, что делает.

Для успокоения совести можно использовать тег [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript), который отображет свое содержимое, если JavaScript отключен или не поддерживается. Добавьте куда-нибудь в `index.html` код на подобии этого:

```
<noscript>
    Чтобы страница могла отобразиться правильно, необходим JavaScript.
    По-видимому, JavaScript либо отключен, либо не поддерживается вашим браузером.
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Использовать тег [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp), он как раз для этого и придуман.